# How textinput works with value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<TextInput
  value={'abc'}
  //onChangeText={v => this.props.reduxAction({ prop: 'someprop', value: v })}
/>
```

What I don't understand is that, when loaded the screen, TextInput starts with value "abc", but when typing, the value still managed to change? Shouldn't it go back to "abc" regardless what you type since we don't have a `onChangeText` defined?

Comment: no, as I understand the component will behave in this way if the `value` prop does not change

Comment: @DacreDenny: then it sounded like `value` prop doesnt go along with the actual value of the textInput?

Comment: Its internally handled in `TextInput` component via states.

Comment: @kiranvj: Good to know. Not like usually will have a problem with it, just kinda shocked to find out haha. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - bit late coming back to you. Yeah my understanding on this is a little vauge but as I understand, the `<TextInput />` maintains state internally. It will only update itself if the value prop actually changes during a re-render (which is typically how it's used). If the prop value is static, then it'll behave in the way you're observing (but won't be too useful)

Comment: I think there is a `defaultValue` prop that takes the place if text is empty. Or you can put some logic in your `onChange`, that sets it to some value if the length is 0

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question.

**Step1:**
We should pass value through state.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {
      value: 'abc'
    };
  }
```

**Step2**: 
Change texts

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.value}
  onChangeText={v => {
  this.setState({
     value: v
    })
 }}
/>
```